# Where does curses inject KEY_RESIZE on endwin and refresh

Tags: ncurses, python-curses

Run this Python code and resize window. It will get a `KEY_RESIZE` and exit.

```
import curses
import signal

stdscr = None

def handler(num, _):
    curses.endwin()
    stdscr.refresh()

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.cbreak()
stdscr.keypad(1)
stdscr.refresh()
signal.signal(signal.SIGWINCH, handler)
while True:
    ch = stdscr.getch()
    if ch == curses.KEY_RESIZE: break
curses.endwin()
```

Where is this `KEY_RESIZE` injected?

---

I also tested with C code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <signal.h>

WINDOW *stdscr = NULL;

void handler(int num) {
    endwin();
    wrefresh(stdscr);
}

int main()
{
    stdscr = initscr();
    cbreak();
    keypad(stdscr, 1);
    wrefresh(stdscr);
    signal(SIGWINCH, handler);
    while (1) {
        int ch = wgetch(stdscr);
        if (ch == KEY_RESIZE) break;
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Run it and resize it, then *press a key*, it will get a `KEY_RESIZE` exit. Why do we have to press a key to get a `KEY_RESIZE` in C code, which is not necessary in Python code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's by design... since curses doesn't have anything like an event-loop, it has to tell the application that a `SIGWINCH` was detected, and that the curses library has updated its data structures to work with the new terminal size.  (Having a signal handler in the application that an application could use to *tell* the curses library would not work better, and having the curses library do this is simpler, anyway).

The [`initscr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Signal-Handlers) and [`getch`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Predefined-key-codes) manual pages mention this `SIGWINCH` feature.

As for "where" it does this: that's in [_nc_update_screensize](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/ncurses/tinfo/lib_setup.c#L428), which checks a flag set by the signal handler, and is called from several places including `doupdate` (which `refresh` and `getch` call).  That will inject a `KEY_RESIZE` whether or not there was actually a `SIGWINCH`, if the screensize has changed.

Now... it's possible to have signal handlers *chain*, by calling the original handler from newly-established handlers.  (Calling `signal` in a C program returns the current handler's address).  ncurses will only add its handler at initialization time, so one (unlikely) possibility is that the python code is perhaps reusing the underlying handler when it adds its own.

However, there's a larger problem in the examples: they are making curses calls in the signal handlers.  That's unsafe in C (the reason why ncurses' signal handlers only set a flag).  Perhaps in python those handlers are wrapped -- or just due to timing you're getting unexpected behavior.

Comment: I overlooked `ncurses/tty/lib_tstp.c` which looks like a file for `SIGTSTP` but actually more than that. It is where `SIGWINCH` handler `handle_SIGWINCH` gets installed, in `_nc_signal_handler` using `CatchIfDefault`. That handler sets a global flag `_nc_globals.have_sigwinch`, which is later checked in `_nc_handle_sigwinch` (called by `_nc_wgetch` and `TINFO_DOUPDATE`) , which moves the global sigwinch flag into each screen. Then the screen sigwinch flag is checked in `_nc_update_screensize` which `ungetch` a `KEY_RESIZE`. Overall, the actual signal does a simple thing: Set a global flag.

Comment: But this doesn't fully answer the question yet. For example, why C and Python programs demonstrate different behaviors when users install their own `SIGWINCH` handler in the application? In this example the user sig handler doesn't set the global flag (as the lib sig handler would do), but it is following the standard approach of `endwin` + `refresh`. Isn't this expected to work well with a user `SIGWINCH` handler? Source: https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html

Comment: If I understand it correctly, a signal handler can possibly run anywhere anytime in the C code? When using the default library `SIGWINCH` handler, do we have a guarantee that everything will still work properly even if a `SIGWINCH` comes in the midst of executing important functions such as `doupdate` (for example, `SIGWINCH` comes right after `_nc_handle_sigwinch`)?

Comment: Another issue is, what if the application wants to handle a window resize **responsively**? Defining a `SIGWINCH` handler in the app looks the most responsive. Otherwise, the app has too loop on `getch`. Very likely the app has other events to take care of, so the loop on `getch` has to be non-blocking. If the loop has a timeout, then it becomes less responsive. If the loop doesn't have a timeout, then it'd be spinning on `getch`, but is that efficient enough?

Comment: You can set a timeout for getch, so that it's not "spinning", e.g., wait up to 10msec.  That works well enough for most applications.

Comment: Well, I prefer use as few timeouts as possible in event-driven programming. Timing bugs are too difficult to diagnose. Here good news is that `endwin` + `refresh` should work in C. And I can probably still use a custom `SIGWINCH` handler. But that handler must be registered without `SA_RESTART` to not `read` twice...

Comment: Your updates point out a meaningful problem: making curses calls in the signal handlers is unsafe in C. A Python signal handler is not wrapped in C signal handler, but the doc says little about when the Python signal handler will be executed. Could you please explain in more detail what makes calling curses functions in C signal handler dangerous?

Comment: Signals can interrupt functions such as malloc in leaving it in an unpredictable state (and causing the program to crash).  There's similar cases in stdio functions being interrupted.

Comment: That sounds fire. I didn't check all the curses functions. By any chance, is there any of them specifically marked as signal-safe? If users define their own `SIGWINCH` handler, what can they safely do w.r.t. curses (call which functions, modify which variables, etc.) in their signal handler?

Comment: For that - see the topic of signal safety, e.g., [this manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185476/discussion-between-cyker-and-thomas-dickey).

Comment: @Cyker Yup. A signal can be delivered at any time. There's even the `errno` code `EINTR` for this very purpose: to say the function was interrupted. The `select(2)` call comes to mind as one place you would check this (amongst others). `select(2)` has a lot of portability issues and including with signals but it's a very useful syscall nonetheless. There's much more to it than this as well as how to safely write signal handlers (etc.) but yes it can happen at any time, really. And why shouldn't it be? Of course even that is a simplification and there might be subtleties I'm not thinking of!

Comment: Also another way to handle a resize (it won't work necessarily for all purposes but some) without even worrying about signals: have an initial call to `getmaxyx()` and then in the loop have another call that stores the current max y/x. Depending on what you need to do if it resizes it can be done. I thought of this for different uses in programs of my own and it greatly simplifies things. Won't work for all cases but for those it does it's a good way round the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas answers where `KEY_RESIZE` comes from. That is a great introduction for me to debug the C code and answer the second question about the key press.

The short answer is given as working code (with a potential problem arising from calling ncurses functions in signal handlers, see Thomas updated answer, but does not seem to be root cause of the problem here):

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <signal.h>

WINDOW *stdscr = NULL;

void handler(int num) {
    endwin();
    wrefresh(stdscr);
}

int main()
{
    stdscr = initscr();
    cbreak();
    keypad(stdscr, 1);
    wrefresh(stdscr);

    struct sigaction old_action;
    struct sigaction new_action;
    new_action.sa_handler = handler;
    new_action.sa_flags = 0;        //  !
    sigemptyset(&new_action.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGWINCH, &new_action, &old_action);

    while (1) {
        int ch = wgetch(stdscr);
        if (ch == KEY_RESIZE) break;
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

The long answer is tedious.

Basically, ncurses expects the `SIGWINCH` handler to be installed without the `SA_RESTART` flag.

The ncurses library calls `fifo_push` defined in `ncurses/base/lib_getch.c` to read input stream. And that function has a blocking `read` when you blocking `getch`.

On `SIGWINCH`, this call is interrupted, and returns `-1` with `errno` set to `EINTR`.

The ncurses library will handle this in `_nc_wgetch`, which calls `_nc_handle_sigwinch` to check if a `SIGWINCH` happened. If so, it then calls `_nc_update_screensize` to `ungetch` a `KEY_RESIZE`.

So far so good. But what if we have used `SA_RESTART` when installing the `SIGWINCH` handler? The `read` system call will be restarted on interrupt. This is why the C program does not exit immediately after a window resize but must read another key press.

More interesting is, ncurses expects `SA_RESTART` to be set when installing signal handlers (in `ncurses/tty/lib_tstp.c`):

> Note: This code is fragile!  Its problem is that different OSs
>     handle restart of system calls interrupted by signals differently.
>     The ncurses code needs signal-call restart to happen -- otherwise,
>     interrupted wgetch() calls will return FAIL, probably making the
>     application think the input stream has ended and it should
>     terminate.  In particular, you know you have this problem if, when
>     you suspend an ncurses-using lynx with ^Z and resume, it dies
>      * immediately.

But `SIGWINCH` is an exception...

```
#ifdef SA_RESTART
#ifdef SIGWINCH
    if (sig != SIGWINCH)
#endif
    new_act.sa_flags |= SA_RESTART;
#endif /* SA_RESTART */
```

The original C code fails because `man signal` says:

> By  default,  in  glibc  2  and later, the signal() wrapper function does not invoke the kernel system call.  Instead, it calls sigaction(2) using flags that supply BSD semantics.

And the BSD semantics are:

```
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
```

Python? Python doesn't bother with `SA_RESTART`:

```
PyOS_sighandler_t
PyOS_setsig(int sig, PyOS_sighandler_t handler)
{
#ifdef HAVE_SIGACTION
    ...
    struct sigaction context, ocontext;
    context.sa_handler = handler;
    sigemptyset(&context.sa_mask);
    context.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(sig, &context, &ocontext) == -1)
        return SIG_ERR;
    return ocontext.sa_handler;
#else
    ...
#endif
}
```

Comment: Maybe this answers my question, does it say why only once KEY_RESIZE is read and then nothing else can be read?

[My question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012481/after-key-resize-no-more-input-is-read-by-getch)